# What word class is "yeah yeah"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In an episode of the Graham Norton Show, Norton is speaking with Matthew McConaughey and Anne Hathaway. He asks Hathaway to tell them about her initial feelings about working with McConaughey. She is nervous to do so but agrees, saying:

> I was excited to work with Matthew—yeah yeah, I mean who wouldn’t be? He’s amazing.

In this context, what part of speech would the word *yeah* be considered to be? I originally thought an interjection, but I am unsure.

Comment: The word you’re looking for is _word class_ or _part of speech_. I’ve edited your question to use those terms to make it easier to understand, and also added some formatting.

Comment: Is a better transcription perhaps 'I was excited to work with Matthew ... yeah ... yeah, I mean who wouldn’t be?' with two _yeah_'s and nervous pauses? Then, 'yeah' can be seen as a nervous filler, obviously affirmative. 'Interjection' works better than any other traditional word class, though I see 'pragmatic markers' as a superclass.

Answer (score -2):

Use of "yeah" twice, to interrupt, is a [volitive interjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection#Meaning_and_use); and [passive aggressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive-aggressive_behavior).

Comment: However, that's not the way in which it's being used here. Here, I believe it's simply an elided form of "Yes, I know." (BTW: I'm not the person who downvoted you. )

Comment: There's no reason why "yeah, yeah" has to be passive aggressive (though I agree it _can_ be in some cases); in particular, in this context it does not appear to be.

Comment: Repetition for emphasis is common. "No, no" (or even more times) is also commonly heard as a denial.

Comment: @psmears Even four years later I stand by my answer, having seen the show and English is my first language.

Comment: @Rob: I'm not sure who the "he" is that's agreeing with "himself"? It's Anne Hathaway who's speaking throughout the whole of the quote in the question.

Comment: Both of who are what? You're making no sense!